# Convert Sql Server Spatial data to GeoJSON & plot on map

Tags: c#, jquery, sql, asp.net-mvc-3, geojson

I have a sql server table with Geo spatial data. An example of row would be (with Column names):

```
type: streetline
code: 231001
geog: 0xE6100000011 ........
Centroid 0xE61000000C.......
geom: 0xE6100000011 ........
```

I am using C# with MVC3 to draw the above shapes on leaflet map. I am fetching the above sql data into a datatable. Using the sql function "ToString()" on column "geom" I get the following:

```
"LINESTRING (-1.131510412 52.65531, -1.13286 52.65559)",
"POLYGON ((-1.1116360 52.6409953, -1.1116683 52.6413, -1.11146723 52.641317, -1.11133263 52.6413572, -1.1113059))",
```

The question is how do I convert the above to GeoJSON to be able to plot on the leaflet map. Here is an example of the expected output (GeoJSON) I want:

```
var geojsonFeature = {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "name": "Coors Field",
        "amenity": "Baseball Stadium",
        "popupContent": "This is where the Rockies play!"
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-104.99404, 39.75621]
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use SQL function to convert spatial to GeoJSON:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2016/01/13/returning-spatial-data-in-geojson-format-part-2/

If you have Sql2016 with JSON support or Azure SQL Database you can export full result set as GeoJSON.